# Downloading a video from a server, but don't want to see videos in gallery

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, download

I am successfully able to download videos from sever but and I can see them in gallery. Is there any way to hide downloaded videos from gallery. We have this requirement for Unity 3D for android platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the download code

Answer (score 1):

You can place a blank file named `.nomedia` inside your download folder.

When the media scanner detects the `.nomedia` file, the media scanner does not scan that folder so the images and videos in that folder don't appear in the Gallery.

Comment: Thanks @marlove, your answer is only helpful to hide files from scanner. But if I go android -> Data -> my app files the I can still able to see my files. Is there any way to hide this also? My query was on hiding files completely (not only from scanner).